# $\dim(\mathbb{V}_1 \oplus ...\oplus \mathbb{V}_k) = \dim\mathbb{V}_1+...+\dim\mathbb{V}_k$

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

Problem:

If $\mathbb{X}$ is a vector space and  $\mathbb{V}_1 \oplus ...\oplus \mathbb{V}_k$ ($k \leq n$) a direct sum of subspaces of $\mathbb{X}$. Show that

$$\dim(\mathbb{V}_1 \oplus ...\oplus \mathbb{V}_k) = \dim\mathbb{V}_1+...+\dim\mathbb{V}_k\leq{n}$$

Some hint, please.

Comment: How do you show what the dimension of anything is? You find a basis of that size. Since bases are sets, you need to ask yourself what operation on sets corresponds to the operation you are doing with the dimensions: i.e. adding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have (for subspaces $\mathbb V_1$ and $\mathbb V_2$ of $\mathbb X$)
$$\dim(\mathbb V_1\oplus\mathbb V_2)=\dim(\mathbb V_1)+\dim(\mathbb V_2)
-\dim(\mathbb V_1\cap\mathbb V_2). $$

Prove this, then you can generalize to $k$-many subspaces. Hope I helped!

Comment: I thought about that. But, I'll have 
$\dim(\mathbb{V}_1 \oplus ...\oplus \mathbb{V}_k)=\dim\mathbb{V}_1+...+\dim\mathbb{V}_k-\dim\mathbb{V}_1\cap\mathbb{V}_2-...-\dim\mathbb{V}_{k-1}\cap\mathbb{V}_k+\dim\mathbb{V}_1\cap\mathbb{V}_2\cap\mathbb{V}_3+...$ or just $\dim(\mathbb{V}_1 \oplus ...\oplus \mathbb{V}_k)=\dim\mathbb{V}_1+...+\dim\mathbb{V}_k-\dim(\mathbb{V}_i\cap(\mathbb{V}_1+...+\widehat{\mathbb{V}_i}+...+\mathbb{V}_k))$

Comment: @MatheusNunes But because this is a direct sum the dimension of the intersections of the subspaces vanishes.